# Include all pages in tampermonkey(userscript)

Tags: userscripts, tampermonkey

I have to include all sites in tampermonkey..this is the script that i have to run

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Phishing Blockz
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description Phishing block based on hyperlinks
// @match      http://*/*
// @run-at     document-end

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.status;
var locheader=req.getResponseHeader("Location");
alert(headers);
alert(locheader);
```

Have I done something wrong.please help me to run this userscript in all pages in chrome

Comment: At least show your script!  The URL "trimming" is just a display choice, it is not the problem.

Answer (score 97):

```
// @match      http://*/*
```

will only match addresses starting with ***http://...*** but not ***https://...*** for example.

Use the following to include ***all*** addresses if that's what you really require (including local pages you may have saved on your hard-drive!)..

```
// @match      *://*/*
```

Note: The method below also works at the time of writing by virtue of a potential bug or undocumented feature in TM2.12 (so could well be subject to change in future versions!!):

```
// @match      *
```

Comment: `@match *` is not a valid pattern. See the doc page and there can be more than one `@match` line.  The OP's metadata block is corrupt and the OP appears to have abandoned this question.

Comment: Shame on OP if has abandoned, though it's still a useful QA.
Would the generally correct syntax be _// @match      *//*/*_  ?
For the record I have scripts with _match *_ working under TamperMonkey 2.12!

Comment: Close, you need the colon. See [the doc](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html).  That's interesting about `*` in Tampermonkey.  I'm going off the Chrome rules -- which are supposed to be the master for `@match` in both Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey.  I wonder if Tampermonkey works despite the error -- while Chrome does not.  I'll test this at some point.

Comment: I did try it in TM before answering/commenting on the question which is specific to TM - and it definitely works ;)

Comment: Okay tested it myself and `*` works while `<all_urls>` does not!  There is no error in Tampermonkey, even in verbose mode, for either one. This is all a bug, AFAIC, and it's not consistent with Chrome nor Greasemonkey.  Still, your answer is more correct than I thought. +1.

Comment: Tampermonkey is documented as not supporting <all_urls>, so that is a feature. On further investigation I concur _match *_ is a deviation from the Chrome extensions documentation which TM offers as a reference (in lieu of stand alone documentation), so this is a bug. I will amend my answer (and scripts!) to future-proof.

Comment: `<all_urls>` is not meant to be matched literally. The doc was written like that to mean `http://www.google.com/` or `http://www.facebook.com/` or `https://stackoverflow.com/`, in other words any valid url can be matched exactly to only run on that url page.

Comment: Tampermonkey no longer supports '*", so use the more appropriate suggestions shown here now...

Answer (score 19):

> `// @match        *://*/*`

**This should find all URLs.** Using *TamperMonkey/GreaseMonkey*

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Match Every Site
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.1
// @description  I will pop up on every site!!
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

alert("I am working!")
```

This might be useful for *browser-extensions* on some pages:

- [WebExtensions Match Patterns Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns)
- [Match Patterns Google Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns)

So accordingly: `*://*/*` matches all `HTTP`, `HTTPS`, and `WebSocket` **URLs**.

Comment: not working, scheme has to be a text : 
`// @match https://*/*
// @match http://*/*`

Answer (score 8):

Doing `@include` instead of `@match` works quite nicely

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Phishing Blockz
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description Phishing block based on hyperlinks
// @include     *
// @run-at     document-end
```

this works on all websites across the web (tested in TamperMonkey)

Comment: looks deprecated

Answer (score 5):

The real answer would be to have:

```
// @match https://*/*
// @match http://*/*
```

Comment: Latest documentation from https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_match says that it is possible to simple include `'http*://'.` It does widen the scope, but I think it is highly unlikely there are other protocols that start with http and are not http/https.

Comment: Please upvote this one as there is obsolete answer in any others

Answer (score 0):

For me, using

```
// @match https://*/*
// @match http://*/*
```

DOES NOT work.
Rather, I have to use @include for tampermonkey to load scripts on all pages in my device,

```
// @include https://*/*
// @include http://*/*
```

FYI: I am using tampermonkey in Fennec v105.1(Firefox android version in F-droid) running in android 10